# Redirect all media requests (css, js and images) with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm building an MVC application and I am having some problems with the path of **css files, js and images** in html ... I was given a solution to use the `<base>` tag to define the path that all html files follow, ex : `<base href="http://localhost/mvc/>`, only back and forth had some problems installing javascript plugins, since when I put, for example, `href="#"` that clicking instead not to do any action, the link took me to the URL that was defined with the `<base>` tag would be `http://localhost/mvc/#`, I wonder how I can redirect all "requests" of those files to a subfolder , ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<img src="images/img2.jpg" />
```

All requests led to a subfolder, for example, **PUBLIC**, there would only need to set the html folders within that **public** ...

HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is a client-side problem and so should be solved client-side in the HTML, CSS and JS, not with a redirect in .htaccess. (Even if you did manage to solve it in .httaccess, it would be unnecessarily inefficient.) As you've mentioned, it should be solved by either using the `base` element in the `head` section or by using root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs in your client-side code (ie. _not_ relative). Using relative URLs is ultimately the problem; relative to what?

Answer (score 2):

A relative URL like `abc/def/file.js` within an html file causes the browser (!!) to add the current path in front of it and issue the request. Assumed, you are browsing `http://domain.com/folder/file.html` the result would be `http://domain.com/folder/abc/def/file.js`.

The `<base>` tag is just only changing the referring point of this action, by not taking the current URL's base path, but the value given in base. This needs to be absolute then. And that's where things are usually getting more complicated: try to omit `base` in general!

The `#` does not change anything, as it's the start of a (here missing) fragment. `http://doamin.com/file.js` and `http://doamin.com/file.js#` are literally the same as the `#` is supposed to be interpreted by the browser only and not the server.

Furthermore, if your MVC implementation is doing a `<a href='#' onclick='somejsfunction();' ...` and this is not returning false, you get a reload of the page, which is confusing your view.

Instead, try `<a href='#' onclick='somejavafunction();return false;' ...` which would prevent the `href` from getting executed.

Recommendation: instead of creating a hay-wire of `base` and `.htaccess` settings, start with a clear directory structure and relative path everywhere. In a proper environment you won't need any of those.

Answer (score 1):

You write in your question:

> I was given a solution to use the `<base>` tag to define the path that all html files follow,

That sounds a bit that this kind of "solution" actually introduced problems to your application instead. It also sounds like you were receiving something you could not fully deal with the implications with.

I would normally consider using the `<base>` element within in the design of the hypertext input/output layer of a web-application bad practice. So whoever suggested you that either didn't know or did this by intention. It normally can only be a patch on a concrete document, if you have resolution issues as you can't keep the document URI (e.g. you're mirroring or archiving hypertext documents). This should normally never be the case for a web-application as an application has a base-URI configured so can make use of it as a property when rendering the HTML output. All applications I know of which had used the `<base>` element in the past have dropped it's use.

So the best answer I can give warm-heartedly is to re-think the use of the `<base>`  element in your application and remove it. It is causing you the problems in the first case.